# How to animate the border bottom changing color

Tags: jquery, html, css

So, I have some code and it (is supposed to) changes the `border-bottom` when the `input` is clicked. Here is what I have:

```js
$(function() {
    $("#nameInput").click(function() {
        $("#nameInput").animate({
            borderBottom: "3px solid #2C4B9A"
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

```css
#nameInput {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background: #EDEDED;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #939393;
    font-size: 36px;
}
#nameInput:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>Message Signature</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
        <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "informationContainer">
            <input type = "text" id = "nameInput" placeholder = "Name" spellcheck = "false">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Basically, this is supposed to change the `border-bottom` to blue when the `input`, 'nameInput', is clicked. However, this does not work. I am wondering how I can have the bottom `border` change color when it is clicked.

P.S I am also wondering how I can have it so when it is clicked the color changes and then expands (see `.gif` below):

[image: GIF]

Comment: When I combined the first two answers, I was able to achieve what I was going for (I had it so that when it focuses, it transitions in, and when it un-focuses, it transitions out).

Comment: Hey, I made mine accomplish what happens in the gif and I managed to implement it in purely CSS. you may want to take a look.  Just wanted to make sure you saw it as you have already chosen an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using transitions?

```
#nameInput {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background: #EDEDED;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #939393;
    font-size: 36px;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}



$(function() {
    $("#nameInput").click(function() {
        $("#nameInput").css(“border-bottom”,"3px solid #2C4B9A"
        );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be accomplished purely in CSS by using `:focus-within`.  You can also implement it as a class (which, in  my case, I chose `magicBox`.  By using a class and no JavaScript it makes it easier to add more than one.

```css
.magicBox > input {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background: #EDEDED;
  border: none;
  font-size: 36px;
}
.magicBox > input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.magicBox {
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}

.magicBox::after, .magicBox::before {
  content: ' ';
  width:0%;
  bottom:0px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position:absolute;
  transition:ease-in-out .5s all;
}

.magicBox::before {
  width:100%;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #939393;
}

.magicBox::after {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #3366ff;
}

.magicBox:focus-within::after {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="magicBox">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name" spellcheck="false">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

to just change the border color you simple set the border color on focus.

now, to achieve the same effect in the gif, if i'm not wrong, it's not a border, but another html tag with background-color.

```js
$(function() {
    $("#nameInput").click(function() {
        $("#nameInput").animate({
            borderBottom: "3px solid #2C4B9A"
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

```css
#nameInput {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background: #EDEDED;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #939393;
    font-size: 36px;
}
#nameInput:focus {
    outline: none;
    border-bottom-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>Message Signature</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
        <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "informationContainer">
            <input type = "text" id = "nameInput" placeholder = "Name" spellcheck = "false">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any idea how I would make achieve that in the gif?